# Moving .net control / macro within template by content user

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

If I have a template with a user control/.net control/macro in a specific place (lets say in the left rail of the template), does a content user have control over its position?

Lets say I have a left and right rail, and I want the Content User the ability to move this control/macro from one rail to the other.

Is this possible in Umbraco?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the case that it goes in one place or another, you could create 2 templates and let the editor choose which template to use for a given page.

Or, if you want the user to place the content in an arbitrary location, you would not put it in the template at all, but rather make sure that "Use in editor" is set to "Yes" in the Macro Properties tab (Developer>Macros>Macro Properties)